# Sending PrintWriter to textArea using OutputStream

Tags: java, outputstream

I have a program which is to be a chat program between a client and server. I set the sockets up depending on which button was clicked like this:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Object o = e.getSource();

    if(o==startServer)
    {
        startServer.enable(false);
        try{
            listenSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket client = listenSocket.accept();
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader buffRdr = new BufferedReader(is);
            PrintWriter printWrt = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
            service = 1;
            sendButton.enable(true);
            disconnectButton.enable(true);
            sendText.enable(true);
            more = true;
        }catch(IOException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if(o==connectButton)
    {
        try{
            startServer.enable(false);
            connectButton.enable(false);
            Socket server = new Socket(host,port);
            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader buffRdr = new BufferedReader(is);
            PrintWriter printWrt = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(),true);
            service = 2;
            sendButton.enable(true);
            disconnectButton.enable(true);
            sendText.enable(true);
            more = true;
        }catch(IOException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I run two instances of the program and everything seems to connect but im not sure how the program knows to get the text from the sendText textBox i have set up. Here is how i have my run set up but it never gets to the System.out.println("Service Changed") or where i append "Listening to socket" after the program waits for the service to change from 0.

```
    while(more)
    {
        statusArea.append("Chat Running");
        String line;
        try{
            System.out.println(service);
            while(service==0 && more);
            System.out.println("Service Changed");
            if(buffRdr!=null)
            {
                statusArea.append("Listening to socket");
                while(more && (line=buffRdr.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    chatArea.append(line);
                }
            }       
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Any help on this would be appreciated, im rather new at programming in java

Comment: Do you really have empty catch blocks? You seriously don't want to do this. Next we'll need to discuss Swing threading issues, but only after you fix those empty catches.

Comment: I cannot use swing for this I would rather use all awt in order to get the full knowledge of java. What do you mean by empty catch blocks? I can add the printStackTrace to the one in the run method but my main concern right now is getting at least something to send from the client to the server right now since the program is not finished yet